# "Ridiculously" (expressing absurdly or unbelievably good, bad, crazy, etc.) and "ridiculement"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, argot

> [Remembering Rush's Ridiculously Good Drummer](https://pitchfork.com/thepitch/remembering-rushs-ridiculously-good-drummer-neil-peart-with-5-live-videos/)
>
> ridiculous[ ri-dik-yuh-luhs ] (https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ridiculously)
>   1. adjective causing or worthy of ridicule or derision;
>   absurd; preposterous; laughable: a ridiculous plan.
>
> 2. **Slang. absurdly or unbelievably good, bad, crazy, etc.:**
>
> *The concert was ridiculous, their
>   best performance ever!*

I think that *ridicule(ment)* cannot convey the second (slang) meaning of ridiculous(ly). In this case, how can one convey similar ideas in French?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Une traduction qui s'appuie sur l'idée d'extrême, d'excès ou d'incrédibilité, pour superlative que ces notions puissent sembler, ne va pourtant selon moi pas assez loin pour transmettre l'esprit du *« **ridiculous·ly** »* anglais.

Il est vrai cependant, comme on l'a noté en d'autres réponses, que la notion française de *« **ridicule** »* possède une lourde charge négative. On se positionne et on positionne la grande majorité du monde *au-dessus* de ce que l'on déclare ridicule. Il semble assez difficile, voire impossible, de renverser la vapeur, de retourner le concept comme dans un miroir. Tout au plus pourrait-on éviter la condescendance complète et y distiller un peu d'admiration en laissant entendre par exemple que le batteur a dû pratiquer **un nombre ridicule d'heures** quotidiennement pour atteindre une telle maîtrise de son art.

*« Ridicule »*, donc, ne serait pas un terme à privilégier ici pour la traduction. On peut par contre penser à d'autres concepts moins clairement négatifs. Les opinions pourront varier, mais je crois qu'*« **absurde** »* pourrait fonctionner, si on pense qu'on ne cherche certes pas à déprécier le théâtre d'Ionesco en le qualifiant de théâtre de l'absurde :

> En mémoire du batteur **absurdement** doué de Rush.

D'autres concepts habituellement négatifs, sans l'être aussi fortement que *« ridicule »*, pourraient aussi être évoqués dans un contexte de dépassement d'une limite ressentie a priori comme insurpassable :

> - ***invraisemblable :*** Un concert *invraisemblable*, le plus extraordinaire d'une carrière pourtant ponctuée de concerts légendaires.
> - ***déraisonnable :*** Neil Peart, ce batteur *déraisonnablement* talentueux.
> - ***impensable :*** Un talent *impensable* : les meilleurs prestations du batteur de Rush.
> - ***inconcevable :*** Un *inconcevable* génie de la batterie nous a quitté.

Je note que l'exagération est ici de mise, particulièrement pour les deux derniers exemples (auxquels on pourrait ajouter ***impossible***). Des expressions très fortes de ce genre devraient être utilisées avec parcimonie, au risque de les rendre banales, ou de passer pour quelqu'un qui en beurre toujours trop épais.

Il existe d'autres termes, pas forcément négatifs a priori, possiblement acceptables dans certains contextes *(en gardant encore à l'esprit de se méfier de l'exagération à outrance)* : ***hallucinant, abracadabrant, ahurissant, stupéfiant, prodigieux, surnaturel,*** etc.

<sup>Une analyse strictement personnelle de ces termes m'indique qu'à l'oral, je m'attendrais davantage aux trois premiers *(envisageables aussi dans des écrits destinés à un public plus jeune, disons jusqu'à 16-18 ans),* tandis que les trois derniers relèveraient plus du domaine de l'écrit *(dont fait partie l'exemple indiqué dans la question)*.</sup>

En se permettant un peu de liberté sur le mot-à-mot, on pourrait aussi penser à introduire des termes comme ***magicien*** ou ***visionnaire.***

<sub>À propos de ***magicien***, on pourrait, dans le cas particulier d'un batteur, mettre à profit le terme [*baguette*](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/baguette), applicable aussi bien à l'outil du magicien *(baguette magique)* qu'à ceux du percussionniste. Ce rapprochement n'est pas aussi naturel en anglais (magic wand vs drum sticks), mais quelqu'un pourrait décider de ne pas se priver des possibilités de la langue cible.</sub>

---

Je me surprends à avoir oublié la version orale québécoise de la chose, qui vaut ce qu'elle vaut mais n'en est pas moins une réalité (n'en déplaise aux puristes et à ceux qui sont insensibles ou agacés par la flexibilité et la vitalité de la langue orale, de part et d'autres de la mare aux sardines) :

> En mémoire du drummer **vraiment trop hot** de Rush

Answer (score 8):

Je dirai simplement en traduisant un mot de la question: **incroyablement**.

Comment: C'est je pense la traduction la plus directe, avec le même niveau de langage (familier) et c'est ce qui viendrait naturellement dans une conversation

Comment: C'est une remarque intéressante, et il est possible qu'elle soit vraie, quoique je crois qu'il existe différents milieux linguistiques (régionaux, familiers, sociaux, personnels, etc.) qui varient en vocabulaire. Je note malgré tout que l'exemple de la question relève du domaine de l'écrit, et non de la conversation.

Answer (score 5):

As "ridicule" conveys a rather negative meaning, I would use "ridiculement" only for negative opinion:

> Ce téléphone est ridiculement cher
>
> Le service dans ce restaurant est ridiculement lent

I would certainly not use ridicule(ment) for anything positive, so

> Ce concert était ridicule

Will never be positive about the concert, whatever you say after.

To convey a positive meaning, I agree with Mouviciel, "incroyablement" seems really appropriate. You could also use, for example:

> Superbement
>
> Énormément
>
> Extrêmement
>
> Excessivement

Note: the comments had me think a bit further. I can imagine a situation where "ridicule" could be used to a "positive" effect: when you use it to speak about something insignificant, tiny, etc and it's a good thing for this to be so tiny. But then the context should help you understand the context. Example:

> Le prix de ce téléphone est ridicule

Could mean it is either very cheap (if the sentence is used in a promotion for example) or very expensive.

Comment: Agreed, but I think using "ridiculement" (as you do in your first examples) actually brings back the meaning to definition number 1 of the OP (absurd). It's not just a matter of positive or negative meaning.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA To some extent it is a matter of positive or negative meaning, since the example of the question is clearly positive, while the meaning of French *"ridicule"* is rather confined on the negative side of things, according to this answer (and to my own sense of the concept as well).

Comment: @ﺪﺪﺪ: Agreed. What I meant was, the answer is perfectly correct, and you're right to say that "ridicule" is indeed confined to the negative side. What I wanted to point out in my comment is that the usages of "ridicule" cited in this answer are not cases of slang, but used with the word's proper meaning, which is meaning number 1 of the OP. I don't recall hearing any slang uses of "ridicule". But slang is inherenly local to some social circles, so YMMV. I know a friend of mine would have used the word "débile" in the same way as the slang "ridiculous", but he's the only one I've heard it from.

Comment: Your comments had me thinking on the possibility to use "ridicule" for a positive meaning so I updated my answer. To answer the comments now, I don't think my usage is closer to definition 1 or 2, I think these 2 definitions come together in French cause there's no way that something "ridicule" will be "unbelievably good" in French.